# How do I get this script to run periodically via cron?

Tags: scripts, cron

I made a script that sends my local sensors temperature to a server in the internet and then I can see a graph of it. Everything works fine when I execute it manully. I have the latest ubuntu version. 
When it comes to run periodically every minute with crontab then nothing works. It doesnt send anything. I tried to run it as SUDO and as user, I tried to add it in the crontab file to run it from several locations like /bin/myscript.sh , /user/Desktop and many others...Nothing seems to work. 
Any Idea how to solve it? 
Thank you!

```
   echo Init ... 
   TEMP=`/usr/bin/snmpwalk  -v 1 -c public 192.168.1.2 iso.3.6.1.4.1.38783.3.9.0 |  cut -d" " -f4` 
   echo $TEMP


   REALTEMP=`echo  "scale=1; $TEMP/10"  | bc -l`
   echo $REALTEMP 

   echo 
   wget "http://api.thingspeak.com/update?key=MYKEY=$REALTEMP"
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. As is, we have little information we could use to help you. Please consider adding the **script file contents** and the **crontab file contents** for us to be better able to locate the problem's source.

Comment: ok I will do it write away.

Comment: so.. where's the cron / crontab line you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue getting cron to recognize a command on a server of mine. The tip that solved my issue came from the troubleshooting section of the [Ubuntu Cron Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto):

> When adding a new entry to a blank crontab, forgetting to add a
>   newline at the end is a common source for the job not running. If the
>   last line in the crontab does not end with a newline, no errors will
>   be reported at edit or runtime, but that line will never run. See man
>   crontab for more information. This has already been suggested as a
>   bug.

Comment: I *did not* know this, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your crontab line just contains the script name, you need specify what should execute the script, either in crontab (assuming it should run with bash shell)

```
/5 * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/myscript.sh
```

or by adding a ``shebang'' line at the beginning of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It is not obvious that the script depends on any environment variables, but it is worth noting a cron job runs with only `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `PATH`, and `SHELL` set.

The script file also needs to be executable (`chmod +x myscript.sh`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any clue about your script issue, but if your need is to have some realtime charts about the sensors' temperature available through a web server you can give a try to `psensor-server`.

It is available in the standard ubuntu repositories, so you can install it easily with 'sudo apt-get install psensor-server', run 'psensor-server', and finally open the URL 'http://hostname:3131'. You will get this kind of charts:

[image]

Alternatively, you can retrieve programmaticaly as a JSON output the temperatures using 'http://hostname:3131/api/1.0/sensors'.

Comment: Does this support snmp ? My I have a controller that sends back snmp responts that I trap and convert them to charts like this that you have in the screen shoot!

Comment: No, it does not support SNMP.

Comment: So is only for gathering computer statistics! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I manage to do it runing as a service with the help that I found in this [site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=792211)
You can do what he said. Or, you can do this, which will run ANY sript for you.

1. First, create a script, and edit it to your needs. Lets say, you call it, autorun.sh
2. Copy that script into /etc/init.d
3. Run the following commands:

   `sudo update-rc.d autorun.sh defaults`

   `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/autorun.sh`

Again thank you all for your advices. I really didnt have time to check them all. I will do it soon!