# Linux system equivalent to MS-DOS .bat file

Tags: command-line, scripts, automation

I would like to write files that when opened open a terminal window and perform a series of commands, the reason for this is I want to eventually schedule them to run hourly, daily etc, and some of which I want to eventually run as background processes (data mining) continually.

I'm really sorry in advance if I am difficult to understand here, I am very amateur as far as computer science and programming is concerned, so I am just describing my objectives as best as I can without knowing the formal terminology.

Comment: Also see [How do I get this script to run periodically via cron?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185845/)

Comment: for executing scheduled scripts, you can use **cron** and/or **anacron**. The latter is better suited for a computer that does not run continuously.